# Unable to connect to Wifi Router (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a Dlink signal antenna wifi router. It takes alot of time to connect to the wifi even when the signals are at full strength, but if I take the device to the router, the device gets connected. Some times I am unable to connect to the router at all.

I want to know what is causing this problem. How can I solve this issue? I am attaching the picture of my wifi router.

[image]

Kindly guide me in solving this problem.

I am using windows 7.

Comment: Did you also checked your USB wifi network card ..sometimes it looks like they are working but they're not working properly.

Comment: this problem is with all cell phones and laptops

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate?

What do you mean by "but if I take the device to the router"?  Are you physically taking it over and plugging it in, or are you saying it connects wirelessly if you bring the laptop closer?  If it's the latter, I'd say look at possibly changing the channel from 11 to something else, and possibly start looking at what is blocking the signal.

Comment: if connects wirelessly if I bring the laptop near the router

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mike is right at this point it maybe a channel network issue

check this tutorial here:
[Change Your Wi-Fi Router Channel to Optimize Your Wireless Signal](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21132/change-your-wi-fi-router-channel-to-optimize-your-wireless-signal/)

And tell us how it went..